# Changing the context with knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm being lazy and just posting a link to my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keroger2k/AadrF/10/).  I'm struggling with trying to get the context right.  If you look at the fiddle and type anything into the input box it will render out a template with contacts.  You can hover over them and Edit/Delete will appear, but when I click on them it doesn't work the way I want.  I can get it to call removeContact() on the Contact object if I create that method, but that isn't what i want.  I want it to call removeContact() on the viewModel, but the contact doesn't know about viewModel.  Obviously I'm just playing around with knockout because it is very interesting.  Anyone have any thoughts on how I can get edit and delete to call the removeContact/editContact methods on my viewModel object?

Thank you!

Here is the link again: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keroger2k/AadrF/10/)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/AadrF/14/

Issues:

1. First you were using `${Id}` to access the contact id inside the template. Javascript is case-sensitive so it should be `${id}` (This comes from `this.id` in Contact constructor)
2. In the template, when you want to access the current object you use `$data`. You were using `contact` . Template doesn't know what the heck `contact` is. So you change `viewModel.removeContact(contact)` to `viewModel.removeContact($data)` . Same for edit contact.
3. Remove the `var` from `viewModel` declaration. Now theoretically speaking `viewModel` is global and should be accessed by knockoutjs too but I think it has something to do with jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the catches with items one and two.  The main question I had was being able to access viewModel.  I see you can just remove 'var' from viewModel and that will make it global, but I was hoping to avoid that if possible.  None of the examples on knockoutjs don't use 'var'.  Also you can elminate the 4 windows by going to http://jsfiddle.net/AadrF/14/show

Comment: One thing to note about your fiddle is that under Choose Framework, you have it set to `onLoad`, this will execute your JavaScript in a function that is run onLoad.  So, any variables in there will not have global scope. If you change it to `no wrap (body)` it will simply place your JavaScript in a script tag in your body.  Then, `var viewModel` would be global.

Comment: Also, if you can't use a global variable, then look at the `templateOptions` parameter to the `template` binding, as it will allow you to pass in properties/methods/objects that you otherwise could not access.  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_6_passing_additional_data_to_your_template_using_

Comment: @RPN: Can you pass the viewModel object itself as part of templateOptions ? How can we do that? `templateOptions: {viewModel: this }` ?

Comment: I think that in this case `this` will be the window object.  The only way that I know of is to nest templates and use $data.  So, you would have a `mainTemplate` that takes in the whole viewModel and then use `$data` in your templateOptions when using foreach against an array.  I'll have to play around with it to see if there is a way without the intermediate template.